# YouTube API v3 error on auth "X-Frame-Options is set to SAMEORIGIN"

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-javascript-api

Alright so I've tried to run the youtube samples from the [google developer docs (specifically authorizing_requests)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#authorizing_requests)

1. I downloaded [this repo (youtube/api-samples)](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples)
2. I created a new project in [the google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project)

   like so:
   [image: projects manager]
3. enabled all 3 YouTube APIs from here: [image: YouTube APIs]
4. created API and OAuth key/clientID like so: [image: keys]
5. left the "Accept requests from" field empty so it will accept them from all domains: [image: accept requests from]
   a. **even when I did provide one it didn't fix it btw**
6. in the sample code we are instructed to replace this variable with our clientID like so: [image: clientID]
7. It doesn't matter whether I run it from localhost, or from a proper host this is what I continuously get this on load from any of the sample files like: `search.html`, `my_uploads.html` or any of the other files.

> Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=217603943332-cuo3i85935…angroup.com&response_type=token&state=1069982666%7C0.2949761402&authuser=0' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed the OAuth approval page inside an iframe. Use `target="_parent"` on your auth `<a>` link so the page opens in the parent window.